Annotating taxable events with their tax impact
I would like to incorporate my taxes in my personal finance system. Some transactions come with an increase in your tax liability (e.g., income) and some come with a decrease (e.g., donations are often tax deductible). It seems useful to annotate this information in my books system. That way, you have your own independent computation of how many taxes you owe.
That is to say, normally I might record a salary payment like this:
2024-04-26 Salary
+1000 EUR          Assets::Bank
+1000 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed
-2000 EUR          Income::Salary

The second line shows that 1000 EUR were withheld by the employer for taxes, so the amount of taxes I will owe just decreased by 1000 EUR. However, the salary payment also increases my tax liability by increasing my taxable income. We could try to amend the salary transaction like this: (assuming 50% tax rate for simplicity)
2024-04-26 Salary
+1000 EUR          Assets::Bank
+1000 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed
-2000 EUR          Income::Salary
+1000 EUR          Expenses::Taxes
-1000 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed

The two new transactions record that my tax liability increased by 1000 EUR due to the additional taxable income. Another thing we need to handle is things that involve tax deductions, e.g.:
2024-06-17 Donation or other expense with tax benefit
-1500 EUR          Assets::Bank
+1500 EUR          Expenses::Donations
 +750 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed
 -750 EUR          Expenses::Taxes

This records that the deductible transaction decreased the tax liability.
Unfortunately, everything I outlined above has a critical flaw: tax brackets. All of the transactions have the tax rate built-in to the amounts in use. Changing one transaction now requires that you change all of them because it changes the effective tax-rate. This is not desirable. To work around this, I came up with another solution where we introduce a new currency:

Introduce a new imaginary currency called EURTAXSALARY which is used to record taxable income. In all transactions that represent a taxable event, record the tax liability like the above examples do, but do not multiply them by a tax rate and use the EURTAXSALARY currency.

Effectively, the EURTAXSALARY currency encodes the effective tax rate. The above transactions then become:
2024-04-26 Salary
+1000 EUR          Assets::Bank
+1000 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed
-2000 EUR          Income::Salary
+2000 EURTAXSALARY Expenses::Taxes
-2000 EURTAXSALARY Liabilities::TaxesOwed

2024-06-17 Donation or other expense with tax benefit
-1500 EUR          Assets::Bank
+1500 EUR          Expenses::Donations
+1500 EURTAXSALARY Liabilities::TaxesOwed
-1500 EURTAXSALARY Expenses::Taxes

And at the end of the year we compute the final tax like this:
2024-12-31 Compute Taxable Income
-11250 EUR          Liabilities::TaxesOwed
+11250 EUR          Expenses::Taxes
-22500 EURTAXSALARY Liabilities::TaxesOwed
+22500 EURTAXSALARY Expenses::Taxes

The advantage of this approach is that the final "Compute Taxable Income" transaction means that I have a single place where I can do the math involving tax brackets and so on and arrive at a final number. If any accounts contain a non-zero amount of the EURTAXSALARY currency after the EOY transaction, then I know that something has gone wrong. If I have multiple types of income where taxes are computed separately (e.g., both salary and capital gains), then I would need to use different currencies for each kind.
Now come my questions:

The original approach I outlined has a fatal flaw due to tax brackets. Does the proposed solution approach also have a fatal flaw / situations that require careful handling?
Is there more normal way of accounting taxes that achieves the same goals?


I think the more normal way would be to simply maintain a running total of income in the various categories, then feed those totals through a formula based on the tax tables to get current liability.

I don't follow what problem your proposed solution solves.  As someone paid a salary, my primary concern in tracking taxes paid and taxes owed is figuring out whether my employer is withholding too little or too much.  If EURTAXSALARY expenses always match liabilities, I don't see a way to do that.  If you can't do that sort of analysis, I'm not sure what other benefit you'd be gaining.

My primary concern is making sure that by end-of-year, I have paid the taxes I owe for that year. If I owe taxes, then they begin accruing interest on jan 1st, but the Danish government doesn't do the final computation until march. To avoid interest in the meantime, I need to estimate the taxes myself before EOY and make a voluntary payment if necessary. The purpose of EURTAXSALARY is a sort of validation that the EOY entry Compute Taxable Income is up-to-date. I know that it's up-to-date if and only if EURTAXSALARY goes to zero after that transaction.

Tax brackets is not the only flaw.
Income taxes come in different varieties. The most common are flat tax, marginal rate tax, at source tax, and annualized tax.
These can be summarized this way:

Flat: Timing or amount don't matter, every EUR taxed at the same rate.
Marginal: Timing and amount matters, as your income grows you move through brackets until the period ends (usually a year).
At source: Gets withheld by the payer, you never have to pay it yourself. By the time you see the money taxes have been paid. This is usually done based on either flat tax rate, or certain assumptions and projections about your income which may end up being wrong (and then you need to file a tax return to correct).
Annualized: You need to calculate and pay your tax periodically yourself, submitting tax return and payments to the authorities (accounting for at source withholding and estimated payments and such).

Your actual taxes may be a combination of all of that. Take for example the US:
Salary income includes some portion of taxes withheld at source based on your estimated marginal tax rate projected over the year. Dividend income and capital gains can be taxed at different schedules of marginal rates depending on various parameters that are retroactive. Certain types of income (like depreciation recapture or collectible gains) are taxed at flat rates, but not at source. All of that you need to compile yourself on an annualized tax return and submit after years end.
Similarly expenses - some depend on production of income (before or after the expense). For example, investment related expenses are not deductible unless the investments produce income from which to deduct. Others depends on the total volume: for example donations or property taxes on your personal residence are not deductible unless you have high enough amount of those to itemize (and choose to itemize). Some may also be capped, for example you cannot deduct more than $10K in property taxes, or more than half of your income in donations.
So as you go you might not know whether it is taxable/deductible, and how much of the tax effect you'd have. If today is January 1st (tax year start) and you get paid 100EUR - you don't know how much taxes, if at all, you're going to pay. If that's your whole income for the year - then probably none at all. If your total salary throughout the year adds up to 1M EUR, then your effective tax rate may end up being (random number) 30%, which means you need to pay 30EUR taxes from that 100EUR you've got.

Hmm. The entire idea behind EURTAXSALARY is that you don't have to know how many taxes you pay on that Jan 1st 100 EUR income. You just record it as 100 EUR worth of income, and at EOY you have a sum of all EURTAXSALARY entries. Given the sum (i.e. the total income minus deductions), you can compute what tax that corresponds to, taking brackets into account.

The normal way is to project your income from the various sources for the entire tax year.  Then do the same with expenses.
It is no different than a company who has varying expenses and income depending on the month or quarter.
Even if we had a flatter tax structure, each dollar of income has a different taxable impact. Some income is tax free, some is partially taxable, and others are fully taxable. Some expenses have zero impact on taxes, some are deductible and others trigger tax credits.  For example in the United Sates if you donate $100 to a charity it could have no tax impact, or be deductible depending on if you itemize. The brackets just make this even more complex.
Because you are having to forecast the income and expenses, and you can't guarantee that your estimates are perfect, it is hard to know how to assign the tax impact to each expense. Get a raise and your numbers change. Get a bonus and your numbers change. Have your property taxes go up your numbers might change. Lose your job, and all the estimates go out the window.
I do this projection with a spreadsheet based on estimates from the previous year, and actual events from the current year. I don't use double entry accounting to do it.

This answer seems focused on how to project future taxes rather than on how to compute taxes on a year that has finished?

when you try and assign a tax impact to expenses and income that means you are projecting the taxes for this year.
